# Unity button interactable toggle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I want to make a script, that when the image of a sprite is set to something, enable a button, but if it isn't, disable it. This script is my latest attempt, and it only has 1 error which is "The type or namespace name "Button" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Also my script is put directly on the buttons just to make it easier for myself. Here is my script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AgreeDisagreeManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer m_SpriteRenderer;
    void Start()
    {
        m_SpriteRenderer = GameObject.Find("Square").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
    public Sprite Menu,MenuTerms;
    Button ButtonCompo;
    void Update()
    {
        if(m_SpriteRenderer.sprite == Menu || m_SpriteRenderer.sprite == MenuTerms)
        {
            ButtonCompo = GameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
            ButtonCompo.interactable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ButtonCompo = GameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
            ButtonCompo.interactable = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is like my 3rd day ever using unity so if the code is bad, thats why

Comment: also the tag is getting set to unity3d instead of unity2d for some reason. Just in case it is set to 3d, this is a unity 2d project

Comment: The software is named `unity3d` even if a individual project happens to not utilize the third dimension

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

`Button` comes from [`UnityEngine.UI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.html) namespace.

---

These sorts of simple issues are notified by an IDE (ie. Visual Studio), which you can hover like so:

[image]

Clicking on them gives you some solution:

[image]

Though not perfect, but helps a lot with the issues of finding the relevant namespaces or typos.
Specially when you are starting out in Unity and copying code-sources from somewhere, as they may reference to some obscure Unity namespace.

Comment: I tried the examples it says in the image and now it says " 'Button is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.UI.Button' and 'UnityEngine.UIElements.Button' "

Comment: @gingerphoenix10 remove `using UnityEngine.UIElements` if you have so. Given what you are doing, `using UnityEngine.UI` is what you want.